# JPA validation strategy

Tags: java, validation, jpa, jakarta-ee, bean-validation

NetBeans let me choose between three values for the JPA validation strategy: Auto, Callback and None. What does "Auto" mean? Does "Callback" mean the use of @PrePersist, @PreUpdate, and @PreRemove?

Is there a performance hit if I use Auto or Callback if there is no validation to perform?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JPA 2.0 Spec (JSR 317) does not require a Bean Validation (JSR-303) implementation. Validation is optional. Thus, `javax.persistence.ValidationMode` can take different values:

- `Auto` (default) - if a validation provider is available, then validation should occur
- `Callback` - validation is required and a `PersistenceException` must be thrown if a provider cannot be obtained
- `None` - no validation should be attempted and the lack of a validation provider should not cause an exception

This should answer all your questions.

Comment: According to [http://goo.gl/d8L0O](http://goo.gl/d8L0O) and [the spec, chapter 3.6.1.1](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) the three values should all be CAPS.